# On Lichess, how do you promote to a rook with algebraic notation?

Tags: notation, lichess, blindfold-chess

I am a blind chess player on Lichess. I came across a position in which I wanted to promote to a rook. I learned that you can promote by writing like this:

```
a8=n // promote the pawn at a8 to a knight.
```

Thus, I modified it to this:

```
b8 = r // promote the pawn at b8 to a roke.
```

The error it gives me is: "Envilate move."

I'm not sure what I did wrong. How is it done?
Here is the link to the game:
https://lichess.org/QlZNv9I8
It might look stubid because I wasn't playing the game.

Comment: maybe try: b8=r  (without the spaces around the = sign).

Comment: I see that you wrote the following: "// promote the pawn at b8 to a roke." Did you actually type that part into Lichess?

Comment: @Tanner Swett, No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what is wrong. To promote a pawn to another piece, I need to first type the letter in which the pawn is, followed by the position I want the pawn to go, and lastly the equal sign with the piece I want to promote to.

Here is an example:

```
"Promote a pawn to a knight"
ee8=n "promote a pawn to a knight"
```

Here is how it works.

My pawn is at the letter e and I want the pawn to go to e8. So I typed:

```
ee8
```

The pawn should be a knight that is where =n came from.

Again here is the algebraic equation to use:

```
ee8=n
```